# Small open set containing a set of measure zero

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded set of Lebesgue measure zero, $\mu(U) = 0$. Can we find an *open* set $V$ containing $U$ such that $\mu(V) < \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$? Seems intuitive, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: This is implied by the [Regularity theorem for Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularity_theorem_for_Lebesgue_measure).

Comment: Isn't this implied by the definition of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Wonderful - thank you @RobertIsrael.

Comment: @Greg Martin: More precisely, it's an immediate consequence of the (usual) definition of Lebesgue outer measure $\mu^{*},$ and the property itself (generalized to an arbitrary subset $U$ of ${\mathbb R}^{d},$ with $\mu (V) < \mu^* (U) + \epsilon)$ is called *outer regularity*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robert Israel pointed out in the comment, it is implied by regularity of Lebesgue measure. Although the Wikipedia page states it only for the real line, it holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: It holds for all Borel measures on Polish spaces, in fact. See Kechris' book (on descriptive set theory) for a pretty accessible proof.